# dialog - show piped output immediately

Tags: python, dialog

(This is about the ncurses-based Linux tool 'dialog')

I would like to run a program and print its output in a "dialog --programbox" as soon as this output is available. I use this example for testing:

```sh
dummyoutput | dialog --programbox "output" 20 70
```

where 'dummyoutput' is a small Python script, that slowly prints 0 to 4:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print i
```

Currently, the programbox is displayed but all the output is only shown after 'dummyoutput' finishes.

Can it be achieved that each line is shown in the programbox as soon as it is available (one number after every half second)?

Comment: Try `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @jordanm is great and it worked. Then we can easily apply the same principle in the real project.

It is a Java application which uses the log4j logging framework. Besides a FileAppender, I also use a ConsoleAppender to show specific messages directly on the console. The appender has a `ImmediateFlush` property. If set to `true` the output appears on the console - and in the dialog programbox - as soon as it is available.